# Cancel AlarmManager which was set in Service

Tags: android

folks! I have Service, which checks in `onStartCommand()`  whether auto update was set in user preferences and sets AlarmManager update time if needed. So, I want to acomplish following: consider that AlarmManager is alread set, and user turns auto update off, I want to cancel the alarm. The only idea I have is to broadcast custom intent to service that preferences were changed. Is there another way to do it?

**UPD** or I just need to call `stopService()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broadcast is definitely the best way to communicate between an activity/widget and a service.